# How to pass object (getting response from one API ) to different API in same activity

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to pass a request "_id" to hit one API while this "_id" i am getting as a response after hitting another API like below .

Both API are calling in same Activity.

Note : "_id", i am getting as a response after hitting one API, while i want to pass "_id" to another API .

"_id" is getting as a below response:-

```
{
  "success": true,
  "count": 3,
  "logs": [
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "user": "17",
      "__v": 0,
      "value": 125,
      "unit": "litres",
      "savedDT": "2017-03-22T03:44:20.799Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "user": "17",
      "__v": 0,
      "value": 123,
      "unit": "ml",
      "savedDT": "2017-03-22T03:38:21.142Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "user": "17",
      "__v": 0,
      "value": 123,
      "unit": "litres",
      "savedDT": "2017-03-22T03:38:21.142Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

code for getting response "_id"

```
private void getwaterlog(String token) {

        // Tag used to  the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.WATER_All_LOG_API, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();


     try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jObj.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {

                            String count = jObj.getString("count");
                            JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("logs");
                            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject object = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String _id = object.getString("_id");


                                String user = object.getString("user");
                                String __v = object.getString("__v");
                                String value = object.getString("value");
                                String unit = object.getString("unit");
                                String savedDT = object.getString("savedDT");
                            }
```

So How i can get this "_id" as a request to another API in same activity.

I want to this "_id" in below button clicklistener:--

```
  btn_water_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent i = getIntent();

                    String token = i.getStringExtra("token");

                   //String "_id" =
                    deletewater(token,waterId);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Start another  `AsyncTask` to call the other API. Pass the `_id` in the constructor or `execute`` method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: @Prerak Sola I am using Volley Library . How to get this "_id" to different API

Comment: @PrerakSola I want to call this "_id" on  btn_water_delete.setOnClickListener Please check i have added code for same But unable  to pass here .

Comment: If you want to use the `_id` on a different button click, you need to save it somewhere (SharedPreferences maybe) and in `onClickListener` on that button, retrieve the id from storage and pass it to the APi.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AsynTask to call api using HttpClient to make request under doInBackground(). when first request responce is received then make a second request ang get responce

Comment: I am using volley library But I am facing problem to get this "_id" .

Comment: call another api in onResponse(JSONArray response) method of first api calling

Comment: where getwaterlog() is called ??

Comment: In same activity with button click

Comment: One activity which having two buttons in one button click i am calling getwaterlog in which i am getting _id . and want to get this _id on different button click .

Comment: you are created local variable String _id = object.getString("_id");

Comment: then how you can get _id in btn_water_delete.setOnClickListener